# IGListKit Implementation Issues in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iglistkit

I am currently trying to implement IGListKit in my comments section so things will load better and more efficiently. My comments controller looks like so

```
import UIKit
import IGListKit
import Firebase


class NewCommentsViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    //array of comments which will be loaded by a service function
    var comments = [CommentGrabbed]()
    var messagesRef: DatabaseReference?
    var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    public var eventKey = ""
    //This creates a lazily-initialized variable for the IGListAdapter. The initializer requires three parameters:
    //1 updater is an object conforming to IGListUpdatingDelegate, which handles row and section updates. IGListAdapterUpdater is a default implementation that is suitable for your usage.
    //2 viewController is a UIViewController that houses the adapter. This view controller is later used for navigating to other view controllers.
    //3 workingRangeSize is the size of the working range, which allows you to prepare content for sections just outside of the visible frame.

    lazy var adapter: ListAdapter = {
        return ListAdapter(updater: ListAdapterUpdater(), viewController: self, workingRangeSize: 0)
    }()


    // 1 IGListKit uses IGListCollectionView, which is a subclass of UICollectionView, which patches some functionality and prevents others.
    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        // 2 This starts with a zero-sized rect since the view isn’t created yet. It uses the UICollectionViewFlowLayout just as the ClassicFeedViewController did.
        let view = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        // 3 The background color is set to white
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return view
    }()

    //will fetch the comments from the database and append them to an array
    fileprivate func fetchComments(){
        messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("Comments").child(eventKey)
        print(eventKey)
        print(comments.count)
        messagesRef?.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            guard let commentDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else{
                return
            }
            print(commentDictionary)
            guard let uid = commentDictionary["uid"] as? String else{
                return
            }
            UserService.show(forUID: uid, completion: { (user) in
                if let user = user {
                    var commentFetched = CommentGrabbed(user: user, dictionary: commentDictionary)
                    commentFetched.commentID = snapshot.key
                    let filteredArr = self.comments.filter { (comment) -> Bool in
                        return comment.commentID == commentFetched.commentID
                    }
                    if filteredArr.count == 0 {
                        self.comments.append(commentFetched)
                    }
                }
                self.comments.sort(by: { (comment1, comment2) -> Bool in
                    return comment1.creationDate.compare(comment2.creationDate) == .orderedAscending
                })
                self.comments.forEach({ (comments) in
                })
            })
            self.adapter.performUpdates(animated: true)
        }, withCancel: { (error) in
            print("Failed to observe comments")
        })

        //first lets fetch comments for current event
    }

    lazy var submitButton : UIButton = {
        let submitButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        submitButton.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
        submitButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        submitButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSubmit), for: .touchUpInside)
        submitButton.isEnabled = false
        return submitButton
    }()

    //allows you to gain access to the input accessory view that each view controller has for inputting text
    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .white
        containerView.addSubview(self.submitButton)
        self.submitButton.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor, right: containerView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 12, width: 50, height: 0)

        containerView.addSubview(self.commentTextField)
        self.commentTextField.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: containerView.leftAnchor, bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor, right: self.submitButton.leftAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 12, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 180, width: 0, height: 0)
        self.commentTextField.delegate = self
        let lineSeparatorView = UIView()
        lineSeparatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 230, green: 230, blue: 230)
        containerView.addSubview(lineSeparatorView)
        lineSeparatorView.anchor(top: containerView.topAnchor, left: containerView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: containerView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0.5)

        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var commentTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = "Add a comment"
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        return textField
    }()

    func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let isCommentValid = commentTextField.text?.characters.count ?? 0 > 0
        if isCommentValid {
            submitButton.isEnabled = true
        }else{
            submitButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    func handleSubmit(){
        guard let comment = commentTextField.text, comment.characters.count > 0 else{
            return
        }
        let userText = Comments(content: comment, uid: User.current.uid, profilePic: User.current.profilePic!)
        sendMessage(userText)
        // will remove text after entered
        self.commentTextField.text = nil
    }

    func flagButtonTapped (from cell: CommentCell){
        guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

        // 2
        let comment = comments[indexPath.item]
        _ = comment.uid

        // 3
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        // 4
        if comment.uid != User.current.uid {
            let flagAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Report as Inappropriate", style: .default) { _ in
                ChatService.flag(comment)

                let okAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "The post has been flagged.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                okAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
                self.present(okAlert, animated: true)
            }
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertController.addAction(flagAction)
        }else{
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Comment", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                ChatService.deleteComment(comment, self.eventKey)
                let okAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Comment Has Been Deleted", preferredStyle: .alert)
                okAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
                self.present(okAlert, animated: true)
            })
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertController.addAction(deleteAction)

        }
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification){
        if let userinfo = notification.userInfo{

            let keyboardFrame = (userinfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
            self.bottomConstraint?.constant = -(keyboardFrame.height)

            let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow
            self.bottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -(keyboardFrame.height) : 0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: { (completion) in
                if self.comments.count > 0  && isKeyboardShowing{
                    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: self.comments.count-1, section: 0)
                    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.addSubview(containerView)
        collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        view.addConstraintsWithFormatt("H:|[v0]|", views: containerView)
        view.addConstraintsWithFormatt("V:[v0(48)]", views: containerView)
        bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint!)
        adapter.collectionView = collectionView
        adapter.dataSource = self
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
        fetchComments()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
        submitButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }
    //viewDidLayoutSubviews() is overridden, setting the collectionView frame to match the view bounds.
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        collectionView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension NewCommentsViewController: ListAdapterDataSource {
    // 1 objects(for:) returns an array of data objects that should show up in the collection view. loader.entries is provided here as it contains the journal entries.
    func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] {
        return comments
    }

    // 2 For each data object, listAdapter(_:sectionControllerFor:) must return a new instance of a section controller. For now you’re returning a plain IGListSectionController to appease the compiler — in a moment, you’ll modify this to return a custom journal section controller.
    func listAdapter(_ listAdapter: ListAdapter, sectionControllerFor object: Any) -> ListSectionController {
        //the comment section controller will be placed here but we don't have it yet so this will be a placeholder
        return CommentsSectionController()
    }

    // 3 emptyView(for:) returns a view that should be displayed when the list is empty. NASA is in a bit of a time crunch, so they didn’t budget for this feature.
    func emptyView(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return view
    }
}

extension NewCommentsViewController {
    func sendMessage(_ message: Comments) {
        ChatService.sendMessage(message, eventKey: eventKey)

    }
}
```

My section controller looks like this

i

```
mport UIKit
import IGListKit
import Foundation

class CommentsSectionController: ListSectionController {
var comment: CommentGrabbed?
    override init() {
        super.init()
        inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 15, right: 0)
    }
    // MARK: IGListSectionController Overrides
    override func numberOfItems() -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func sizeForItem(at index: Int) -> CGSize {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: collectionContext!.containerSize.width, height: 50)
        let dummyCell = CommentCell(frame: frame)
         dummyCell.comment = comment
        dummyCell.layoutIfNeeded()
        let targetSize =  CGSize(width: collectionContext!.containerSize.width, height: 55)
        let estimatedSize = dummyCell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize)
        let height = max(40+8+8, estimatedSize.height)
        return  CGSize(width: collectionContext!.containerSize.width, height: height)

    }

    override var minimumLineSpacing: CGFloat {
        get {
            return 0.0
        }
        set {
            self.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
        }
    }

    override func cellForItem(at index: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionContext?.dequeueReusableCell(of: CommentCell.self, for: self, at: index) as? CommentCell else {
            fatalError()
        }

        cell.comment = comment
        return cell
    }
    override func didUpdate(to object: Any) {
        comment = object as! CommentGrabbed
    }
    override func didSelectItem(at index: Int){


    }


}
```

When I present the comments controller no data loads. I know my fetch coments wokrs because I took the time to trace it but my collection view seems to not be registering any cells. It is just displaying an empty view. Any insight on what I may have done wrong?

How I send the messages

```
  static func sendMessage(_ message: Comments, eventKey: String,success: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {

        var multiUpdateValue = [String : Any]()

        let messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("comments").child(eventKey).childByAutoId()
        let messageKey = messagesRef.key
        multiUpdateValue["Comments/\(eventKey)/\(messageKey)"] = message.dictValue

        let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
        rootRef.updateChildValues(multiUpdateValue, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
            if let error = error {
                assertionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
                success?(false)
                return
            }

            success?(true)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Where are you registering the `CommentCell` ?

Comment: I mean how would I do that using IGListKit because all of the methods for a traditional collection view dont seem to be present

Comment: ok add `print(comment)` inside `cellForItem` method inside `CommentsSectionController` and see if it prints on the console?

Comment: hmm it seems to never even touch that line @3stud1ant3

Comment: ok now add `print("numberOfItems")` inside `numberOfItems` method to see if that method is being called or not?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 NOPE NOTHING

Comment: Try to add this in your `viewDidLoad` method: `collectionView.register(CommentCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CommentCell")` in `NewCommentsViewController`

Comment: I would also suggest going through this article: https://www.raywenderlich.com/147162/iglistkit-tutorial-better-uicollectionviews

Comment: I did go through that @3stud1ant3

Comment: i dont know I am just lost at this point @3stud1ant3

Comment: Ok then please add `print("comments = \(comments)")` inside `func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter)` for class `NewCommentsViewController` and see if it is being called  and see if comments is empty or not

Comment: @3stud1ant3 okay when I go there comments is empty

Comment: @3stud1ant3 and when i print it, it prints an empty array

Comment: If you move this line `self.adapter.performUpdates(animated: true)` after `if filteredArr.count == 0 {
                        self.comments.append(commentFetched)
                    }
 ` , see what is the behaviour and what is printed for `comments`?

Comment: it is still empty @3stud1ant3

Comment: Ok please add `print(comments)` after `if filteredArr.count == 0 { self.comments.append(commentFetched) }` and see what does it print?

Comment: okay it actually pulled the comments

Comment: I am kinda lost though

Comment: Ok one thing we can try to make sure that everything else is working: Just make a dummy comment and append it to `comments` array inside `func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable]` and see if it is displayed on the screen , please try this

Comment: okay will do @3stud1ant3

Comment: Yeah im actually getting an error before I even try to add it
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x608000222d40> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}'

Comment: How did you add the comment? please show the code

Comment: see edits please. Also I did not even get a chance to add the comment it crashed as soon as I tried to type something @3stud1ant3

Comment: Yeah as soon as I interact wit the keyboard it crashes @3stud1ant3

Comment: It has to do with the way the keyboard tries to make things autoscroll to the bottom i beleive @3stud1ant3